# Default & Overloaded Constructors in C++ header/implementation files?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'm working on C++ homework. I'm hung up on getting a default constructor and overloaded constructor to work in header / implementation files. I keep receiving an 'expected primary expression before '(' token' error, and stackoverflow and google fu hasn't helped so far.

Main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Triangle.h"
#include "triangle.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Triangle first;

    // show that default is properly built
    cout << "Default is 3, 4 5 triangle, should be scalene and right" << endl;
    cout << " for default a is " << first.getA() << " b is " << first.getB() << " c is " << first.getC() << endl;
    cout << " default " << (first.isEquilateral() ? "is" : "is not") << " equalateral" << endl;
    cout << " default " << (first.isScalene() ? "is" : "is not") << " scalene" << endl;
    cout << " default " << (first.isIsosceles() ? "is" : "is not") << " isosceles" << endl;
    cout << " default " << (first.isRight() ? "is" : "is not") << " right" << endl << endl;

    // test setter methods
    first.setA(2);
    first.setB(2);
    first.setC(3);
    cout << "Modified is 2, 2, 3 triangle, should be isosceles" << endl;
    cout << " for modified a is " << first.getA() << " b is " << first.getB() << " c is " << first.getC() << endl;
    cout << " modified " << (first.isEquilateral() ? "is" : "is not") << " equalateral" << endl;
    cout << " modified " << (first.isScalene() ? "is" : "is not") << " scalene" << endl;
    cout << " modified " << (first.isIsosceles() ? "is" : "is not") << " isosceles" << endl;
    cout << " modified " << (first.isRight() ? "is" : "is not") << " right" << endl << endl;

    // test overloaded constructor
    Triangle second(4,4,4);
    cout << "Second is 4,4,4 triangle, should be equalateral and isosceles" << endl;
    cout << " for second a is " << second.getA() << " b is " << second.getB() << " c is " << second.getC() << endl;
    cout << " second " << (second.isEquilateral() ? "is" : "is not") << " equalateral" << endl;
    cout << " second " << (second.isScalene() ? "is" : "is not") << " scalene" << endl;
    cout << " second " << (second.isIsosceles() ? "is" : "is not") << " isosceles" << endl;
    cout << " second " << (second.isRight() ? "is" : "is not") << " right" << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Header:

```
#ifndef TRIANGLE_H
#define TRIANGLE_H


class Triangle
{
    public:
        Triangle();
        Triangle(int a, int b, int c);
        // accessor methods for a, b, c.
        int getA();

        int getB();

        int getC();
        // mutator methods for a, b, c.
        void setA(int x);

        void setB(int y);

        void setC(int z);
        // equilateral triangles have sides of the same length.
        bool isEquilateral();
        // scalene triangles have unequal sides.
        bool isScalene();
        // isoceles triangles have 2 equal sides.
        bool isIsosceles();
        // right triangles use pythagorean theorem a^2 + b^2 = C^2. the other derivation will also word depending
        // on how sides are declared.
        bool isRight();
        // variables set as private so that only the members of Triangle can modify
    private:

        int a, b, c;
};

#endif // TRIANGLE_H
```

Triangle.cpp:

```
#include "Triangle.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Triangle::Triangle()
{
    // constructor setting sides a, b, c.
        Triangle();{
            a = 3;
            b = 4;
            c = 5;
        }
}

Triangle::Triangle(int a, int b, int c)
{
    Triangle(int a, int b, int c){
            setA(a);
            setB(b);
            setC(c);
        }
}
// accessor methods for a, b, c.
int Triangle::getA() {
        return a;
    }

int Triangle::getB() {
        return b;
    }

int Triangle::getC() {
        return c;
    }
// mutator methods for a, b, c.
void Triangle::setA(int x) {
        a = x;
    }

void Triangle::setB(int y) {
        b = y;
    }

void Triangle::setC(int z) {
        c = z;
    }
// equilateral triangles have sides of the same length.
bool Triangle::isEquilateral() {
    if (a == b && b == c && a == c) {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}
// scalene triangles have unequal sides.
bool Triangle::isScalene() {
    if (a != b && b != c && a != c) {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}
// isoceles triangles have 2 equal sides.
bool Triangle::isIsosceles() {
    if (a == b && a != c) {
        return true;
    }

    else if (a == c && a != b) {
        return true;
    }

    else if (b == c && b != a) {
        return true;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }
}
// right triangles use pythagorean theorem a^2 + b^2 = C^2. the other derivation will also word depending
// on how sides are declared.
bool Triangle::isRight() {
    if (((a * a) + (b * b)) == (c * c)) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (((a * a) + (c * c)) == (b * b)) {
        return true;
    }
    else if (((b * b) + (c * c)) == (a * a)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When running the code, I continue to get an 'expected primary-expression before '(' token' error. I'm unable to get past this - any help is appreciated.

Comment: Consider using `unsigned` for the lengths so you don't need to check for negative inputs. Also you can abbreviate to `return a == b && b == c;` for equilateral test &c.

Comment: @Bathsheba That use of `unsigned` types is actually not what many experts consider best practice now; see https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Res-nonnegative

Comment: @DanielH: Then such guys went on to develop languages like Java. No unsigned types. Nice idea. Oh, but we need `char` which is a 16 bit unsigned type in Java. `unsigned` is nice in C++ since its overflow behaviour is well-defined.

Comment: @Bathsheba I do not believe either Bjarne Stroustrup or Herb Sutter designed Java, and Java’s various choices are not the issue here. The issue is that `unsigned` types do not give you much if any of the protection you expect. Having unexpected giant values for side lengths is not actually any better than having negative values, and might depending on context make the issues harder to spot. Well-defined overflow doesn’t help when it’s well-defined to do the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you picked up that syntax for defining constructors.

For the default constructor, you can use:

```
Triangle::Triangle()
{
   a = 3;
   b = 4;
   c = 5;
}
```

Better yet, delegate it to use the other constructor.

```
Triangle::Triangle() : Triangle(3, 4, 6) {}
```

The other constructor can be corrected and simplified by using:

```
Triangle::Triangle(int a, int b, int c) : a(a), b(b), c(c) {}
```

Comment: We're using an open source book that has been less than helpful, and i'm taking the course online. Admittedly this assignment has been more rushed than usual due to life circumstances, so I haven't been as thorough as I should. 

Using the code you've provided above, I am receiving a 'multiple definition of Triangle::Triangle()'. I've done some tinkering, but there's something i'm clearly not understanding.

Comment: @Grimhammer, that's because you are using `#include "triangle.cpp"` in `main.cpp`. Remove that line.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate your help. I'll make a better study of constructors, this seems like a silly mistake in retrospect.